# SpringBoot form submission

Tags: java, spring-boot

It is my first time posting here for help so excuse for any formatting issues.
So I am trying to submit a form but instead of returning me the updated list charity-list its returning me empty /save.[Its returning this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYCvH.png) Can anyone help in giving me pointers?

@Controller
public class charityController {

```
@Autowired
private charityService service;

//get mapping for charity list page
@RequestMapping("charity-list")
public String getAllCharities(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("charities", service.getAllCharities());
    return "charity-list";
}


@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value="/showCharitySearchForm")
public String showCharitySearchForm(Model model, @Param("keyword") String keyword) {
    // create model attribute to bind form data
    model.addAttribute("charities", service.listAll(keyword));
    model.addAttribute("keyword", keyword);
    return "charity-search";
}


@RequestMapping("/showCharityAddForm")
public String showCharityAddForm(Model model) {
    // create model attribute to bind form data
    Charity charity = new Charity();
    model.addAttribute("charity", charity);
    return "charity-add";
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value="/save")
public String saveCharity(@Valid Charity charity, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "charity-add";
    }
    service.saveCharity(charity);
    return "charity-list";
    }
}
```

> Thymleaf form code:

```
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/save}" th:object="${charity}" 
   method="POST">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Charity name: </td>
                <td><input type="text" th:field="*{name}" /></td>
                <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}" th:errors="* 
   {name}">Name Error</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Charity Registration: </td>
                <td><input type="text" th:field="*{registration_no}" /> 
    </td>
                <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('registration_no')}" 
      th:errors="*{registration_no}">registrationNo Error</td>
            </tr>

           
            <tr>
                <td>Charity Purpose: </td>
                <td><input type="text" th:field="*{purpose}" /></td>
                <td th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('purpose')}" th:errors="* 
          {purpose}">Purpose Error</td>
            </tr>
       
            <tr>
                <td><button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button> 
           </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <hr>
    <a th:href = "@{/charity-list}"> Back to Charity List</a>
       </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: 1) Please copy/paste TEXT, not screenshots.  2) Your screenshot shows the form's action is `action="${/save}"`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, instead of sharing the code snippet as an image, it suggested to share it as a code snippet in text for more clarity

Comment: @paulsm4 I have pasted it now. Can you have a look?

Comment: @PrasanthRajendran Please have a look now :) Its my first time sorry

Comment: As I ALREADY SAID: 1) your problem is that the form is going to "/save".  2) Your form's action appears to be "/save".  3) Q: ???What are we missing???

Comment: Okay, I am really confused about what the action should be? @paulsm4

Comment: Q: Where do you *WANT* to go when the user "Submits" your form?  Currently, it's going to "/save".  Because that's where you told it to go :(